Manga in which the crown prince abused his position to take magical scales out of the royal vault
I'm looking for a manga that was set in a school/academy in Europene/ game as in the mc (male)reincarnated in game . I believe it was some kind of romance/comedy.
The crown prince abuses his position to take magical scales (see picture) out of the royal vault.

The scales make it so that two people (who have to duel) can't break their promise. The prince loses and tries to avoid having to do his side of the deal, but his parents (who were away) show up and force him to take the blame.
I belive it was in full color.

Was this full colour? And when you say "magical scale," do you mean like a fish scale?

idk full color
old comparison scale
